# Why are some SNPs assigned to the wrong position or even chromsome

Tags: position, genetics

When lifting my genome wide data I came across the issue, that some rs-numbers have merged. That leads me to the point, that a SNP must have been misassigned to the wrong position once (or even to the wrong chromosome). After some time, laboratories must have realized the mistake and corrected it. In this case the old rs-number is retracted and the "old" rs number is used for that SNP. Ok, so far so good. My question concerns the question, which technical issues or problems can cause such a misaligment:

Which can be the technical reasons, that a SNP is assigned to the wrong position (or chromosome)? How is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DbSNP#Release

See this question, plus ones that follow in the same section:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK44417/#Content.i_heard_that_rs_numbers_are_not

and also this:

https://www.biostars.org/p/8040/

Comment: Thank you! Especially the referenced thread in your third link (https://www.biostars.org/p/2323/) answers my question.